# Passing value from class in java to post it in API

Tags: java, json, api, jax-rs

I have a java class with string CQ, type and Date Schedule time.
I am trying to pass the value to a string in jsonobject so that i can post the value to api using clientbuilder.
I tried in the below methd but it returns http server error 500. Please let me know if assigning values in the below method would not work.

```
String jsonobject = "{\"CQ\": + ${cQ.getCQ()},\"SchedulingTime\": + ${cQ.getScheduleTime()},\"Type\":\"n\"}";
```

Comment: I'd recommend using some JSON-B library for converting POJOs to json. All JAX-RS frameworks have support for it. You can check this simple demo for Jersey: https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2018/august/jersey.php

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have any syntax for automatically interpolating values into a String literal.

You can use string concatenation syntax like this:

```
String jsonobject = "{\"CQ\":" + cQ.getCQ() + ",\"SchedulingTime\":" + cQ.getScheduleTime() + ",\"Type\":\"n\"}";
```

Alternatively, you  might find  it more readable to use the [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) method to substitute these values at runtime:

```
String jsonobject = String.format("{\"CQ\":\"%s\",\"SchedulingTime\":\"%s\",\"Type\":\"n\"}", cQ.getCQ(), cQ.getScheduleTime());
```

If using Java 15 or later (or 13/14 with the preview feature enabled), you also have the option of using the [`String.formatted`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#formatted(java.lang.Object...)) method and [text blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/text-blocks/index.html):

```
 String jsonobject = """
         {"CQ":"%s","SchedulingTime":"%s","Type":"n"}""".formatted(cQ.getCQ(), cQ.getScheduleTime());
```

This syntax allows you to omit the backslashes escaping the single quote characters inside the JSON string.

Comment: Thankyou.. It was fixed using

String jsonobject = "{"CQ":"" + cQ.getCQ() + "","SchedulingTime":"" + cQ.getScheduleTime() + "","Type":"n"}";

Comment: I’m glad it was helpful. If you’re happy with this answer, could you mark it as accepted?

Comment: I just noticed that I had made a mistake in the second and third examples (now fixed). The output was missing double quotes around the substituted strings.